# What does "captured under" mean?

Tags: meaning

> We are dedicated to comply with local laws such as Data Protection
>   Laws captured under the XXX.

In the example above, what does "captured under" mean? XXX refers to a name of a law. I tried searching the meaning of "captured under", but it seemed that this expression is not commonly used. What does it  mean in this context?

Comment: I think it means something along the lines of **gathered/recorded in one place (article, law, etc.) under the name of XXX**: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/under%20the%20name%20%28of%29%20%28someone%2Fsomething%29

Comment: I regard this as peculiar to essentially refer to “laws captured under a law”. Perhaps it is possible but I’d need more context (such as telling me what XXX really is) to be convinced that “captured under” is being used correctly here. If it’s to do with the EU perhaps there is a hierarchy of laws whereby member country laws get “captured under” an umbrella EU law. In a more conventional context I’d expect something like, “...local laws such as the Data Protection Laws **created by** the Privacy Act 1988.”

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps it is truly cross-jurisdictional the “local laws” are in one country and in another country the “XXX” law refers to them and therefore “captures” them.